# Multiple SSH keys - invalid ssh key expired

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I try to log into the IP address
35.192.33.20 -> works
https://http://35.192.33.20/ -> doesn't work

The logs show an invalid ssh key error.

So, I ran this command on my gcp compute engine and it shows multiple ssh keys.

`ls .ssh`

The result showed multiple keys

`google_compute_engine  google_compute_engine.pub  google_compute_known_hosts  home  home.pub  id_ed25519  id_ed25519.pub  ssh-key-dec6  ssh-key-dec6.pub  ssh-key-v1  ssh-key-v1.pub`

I am hoping to connect to the server using ssh. Can anyone help me delete so many of these ssh keys?

Comment: Most of those keys are different types of SSH keys. You must figure out what the client is using before deleting keys on the SSH server side. Warning: do not delete anything unless you know the consequences.

Comment: I tried deleting all of those - but for each of it I got an error result saying file not found. i don't know if there's any impact of it..but the IP address is working for both http and https - 34.135.68.155. And that is success for me now :)